# Phpunit permission test

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have function that take a csv file and generate file content in array.
I need to write a phpunit tests. Goal is represend correctness of behavior when input is not present or unreadable (whether because the file is malformed or due to the lack of sufficient access rights).

I writed some code but i think it is to much simple.

```
public function testFileAcessForOther()
    {
        $fileName = __DIR__.'/../data.csv';
        $permission = fileperms($fileName);

        $this->assertEquals(33204, $permission);
    }
```

I have googled but didn't find much info about this.

Maybe you can help with some another test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `assertFileExists` to assert that file actually exist

Then you can assert file permission with following code

```
$filePermisson = substr( sprintf( '%o', fileperms( $fileToCreate ) ), - 4 );
$this->assertEquals( "0777", $filePermisson );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the PHP manual, it can be used a bit operator:

```php
chmod($file, 0755);

$fp = fileperms($file)
// int(16877) => '40755'

$perm = ($fp & 0777);
// 0755
// int(493)

$this->assertSame(0755, $perm);
```

Or compare converted decimal file permission:

```php
$octStr = decoct($perm);
// '755'
$this->assertSame('755', $octStr);
$this->assertEquals(755, $octStr);
```